# vcl methods + exceptions corrupt memory with bcc64

Tags: 64-bit, c++builder, vcl

My colleagues and I had a strange bug in a C++ Builder program and boiled it down to the following snippet:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream>

void SIDE_EFFECTS() {
    if (StrToFloat("1337")) {
        throw "abc";
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double innocent = StrToFloat("42");
    std::cout << innocent << std::endl;

    try {
        SIDE_EFFECTS();
    } catch (...) {
    }

    std::cout << innocent << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
42
42
```

Actual Output when compiled for 64bit/ReleaseBuild/OptimizationsON:

```
42
1337
```

Compiler (latest 10.1 Berlin version of C++ Builder):

```
Embarcadero C++ 7.20 for Win64 Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Embarcadero Technologies Inc. bcc64 version 3.3.1 (35759.1709ea1.58602a0) (based on LLVM 3.3.1)
```

The internet says [citation needed] that the bug is always in the user program but never in the compiler or standard library, so please enlighten us if/where we do things that are not to be done in C++ / C++ Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there is nothing wrong with this code, so it has to be a compiler bug.  File a bug report at [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

That being said, you should generally stay away from using `catch (...)`. If you are going to catch an exception at all, at least catch what you are expecting and willing to handle:

```
catch (const char *)
```

Let anything unexpected pass through and be handled higher up the caller chain.

I would not recommend throwing a string literal directly.  It is better to wrap it in a [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) or [`System::Sysutils::Exception`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.Exception) based object instead.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void SIDE_EFFECTS() {
    if (StrToFloat("1337")) {
        throw std::runtime_error("abc");
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double innocent = StrToFloat("42");
    std::cout << innocent << std::endl;

    try {
        SIDE_EFFECTS();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error &) {
    }

    std::cout << innocent << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream>

void SIDE_EFFECTS() {
    if (StrToFloat("1337")) {
        throw Exception("abc");
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double innocent = StrToFloat("42");
    std::cout << innocent << std::endl;

    try {
        SIDE_EFFECTS();
    } catch (const Exception &) {
    }

    std::cout << innocent << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In reality we throw/catch other things. Throwing a string and catching everything was our attempt to minimize the example and rule out external influences. We will report it at Quality Portal.